# Lambda mapping column to uppercase

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have a code that uses the python lambda function to convert to uppercase.

```
df['NAME'] = map(lambda x: x.upper(), df['NAME'])
```

But i keep encountering the error

```
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'upper'
```

which could be due to some names having integers in it so i tried putting in a if condition

```
df['NAME'] = map(lambda x: x.upper() if x.isalpha(), df['NAME'])
```

But it doesn't work and prompts me with

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: try `df['NAME'] = map(lambda x: str(x).upper(), df['NAME'])`

Comment: I get the feeling you have mixed dtypes in your Series. Try `df['Name'] = df['Name'].str.upper()`

Comment: Both solutions works thanks :)